# can't show variables value with echo command in a batch script

Tags: batch-file

i'm trying to put together a batch script, but i'm stuck on trying to assign a variable and then show its value with echo command:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

chcp 65001

for /f "eol=| delims=" %%f in ('dir /b') do (   
    set "file=%%f"
    echo %%f | tr -cd "[]()A-Za-z0-9_.\-" > temp.txt
    set /p filename=<temp.txt
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion     
    echo %%f     rem output: system can't write in specified device
    echo %file%  rem output: system can't write in specified device
    echo !file!  rem output: system can't write in specified device
    echo !filename! rem this works: it shows correctly the content of variable filename     
    endlocal    
)

endlocal
exit /b
```

so, what i'm doing wrong?_?

Comment: You need to invoke delayedexpansion [hundreds of SO articles about that - use the search feature] in order to display/use the run-time value of any variable that's changed within a parenthesised series of instructions (aka "code block").

Comment: ok, i changed it, but still have issues. See updated code

Comment: Now we have the question of "works". "works" means "produces the results I expect". "Doesn't work" means "does not produce the result I expect". Without knowing what results you are expecting and what you are getting, it's not possible to analyse the problem.

Comment: sorry!, updated code

Comment: From what you've shown us, since the display of `%%f` `%file%` and `!file!` are all the same, it would appear that `file` is already set before the routine is run (check by displaying before the `for` - `set file` will display the run-time value of any variable beginning `file`). Your `tr` utility appears to be modifying the text `system ... device` to a correct filename (magic!); that you have a file named `system ... device` OR that the contents of the file `temp.txt` are not being altered from their existing value (possible permissions problem?) - not much of which makes much sense.